# Accessing DetailsView fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, detailsview, itemtemplate

I've started creating an online quiz. I am using a DetailsView linked to a sqlDataSource.
Here's my code:

```
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="QuestionDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="QuestionID,QuizID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Quiz">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text_Eng" SortExpression="Text_Eng" ShowHeader="False">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text_Eng") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text_Eng") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Text_Eng") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option1" AccessKey="1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt_1") %>' GroupName="AnswerOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Option_CheckedChanged" />
                                <br />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option2" AccessKey="2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt_2") %>' GroupName="AnswerOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Option_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option3" AccessKey="3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt_3") %>' GroupName="AnswerOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Option_CheckedChanged"/>
                                <br />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

Note that i am not displaying all data retrieved from the sqlDataSource (there are other fields/columns as well) in the DetailsView.

Now, in my code behind, i am showing the next record by changing the PageIndex of the DetailsView upon clicking a button (NextButton) but at the same time, i need to retrieve some data of the currently displayed record so I've put the following in the button's click handler:

```
protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Save off previous answers
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)QuestionDetails.DataItem;

        // Create Answer object to save values
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionID"].ToString();
        a.CorrectAnswer = dr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
        a.UserAnswer = selectedOptionRB.AccessKey.ToString();

        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["userAnswers"];
        al.Add(a);
        Session.Add("userAnswers", al);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Exception!";
    }

    if (QuestionDetails.PageIndex == QuestionDetails.PageCount - 1)
    {
        NextButton.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        QuestionDetails.PageIndex += 1;
        NextButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (QuestionDetails.PageIndex == QuestionDetails.PageCount - 1)
    {
        NextButton.Text = "Finish the Quiz";
    }

}
```

So when i run the code, i get "Exception!" displayed in my Label2 which i setup for testing.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to see exactly what the exception is and fix the problem that it highlights. Don't use the `try`, and just debug and let the compiler break when it raises.

Comment: Thanks @GrantThomas! I've done that and here's what i got: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And it breaks on this line: a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionID"].ToString(); Any ideas? appreciated.

Comment: this maybe because dr["QuestionID"] is returning null. Check first if it contains any data.

Comment: Thanks @Bat_Programmer. I mean my detailsview is populated with data if that's what you mean?

Comment: yea that's what i mean

Comment: @Bat_Programmer when i run the aspx page, the detailsview is filled with data (typically the first record retrieved). but when i try to retrive a value from that record and say display it in a label, that's when it breaks and gives the error!